# Stored Procedure error

Tags: sql-server

I am testing something. I want to write a statement in my stored procedure that raises an exception/error. I do not want the dividebyzero exception. Any other statement that raises an exception will work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RAISERROR statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) for that purpose.